# how to load all tabs data when page loads using jquery tabs

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

i have an requirement like loading all tabs data  by default. right know first tab is displaying and when u click on second tab it is loading.

i want to load all tabs data by default and select first tab.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Tabs load by Ajax if you specify a separate URL for the tab content via an `href` attribute. If your tab content is rendered by a separate page, then you'd have to rewrite to render it inline in the same page, and not use the `href` attribute.

Comment: all tabs have href elements and now it is loading firrst tab only.
is there any way to load all tabs means i need to call all tab href while page loading and make first tab should select

Comment: No, that was my point. You must render the content for the tabs in the same page, rather than pointing to other pages using an `href` attribute.